# Ordering and summing elements of a list based on their indexes

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

Suppose I have a vector.

I assign to every vector index a four-element array, in such a way that index `i` corresponds to `{x1,p1,x2,p2}`, where `x1,x2` range from a $[-n,n]$ interval ($n$ is a constant defined elsewhere, used to define the dimension of my system) while `p1,p2` are either $0$ or $1$. So, if the vector is `{a,b,c,d,...,z}`, for example, for $n=1$, I have

```
1 ------> {-1,0,-1,0}------> a
2 ------> {-1,0,-1,1}------> b
3 ------> {-1,0,0,0} ------> c
...
36------> {1,1,1,1}  ------> z
```

What I want to do now is rearranging the vector in such a way that the indexes are ordered like `{x1,x2,p1,p2}`:

```
1 ------> {-1,0,-1,0}------> a
2 ------> {-1,0,-1,1}------> b
7 ------> {-1,1,-1,0}------> g
8 ------> {-1,1,-1,1}------> h
...
36 -----> {1,1,1,1}  ------> z
```

Then, I'll have to generate another vector summing a+b+g+h as the first element, and so on, summing 4 elements at a time. At the end, I'll have a 9-element vector:

```
1 -----> {-1,-1} -----> a+b+g+h
...
9 -----> {1,1}   -----> j+k+y+z
```

Where `j,k` are the appropriate elements, chosen by the above rule.

What I do is writing a function that gives me all the 4-elements arrays with `x1,p1,x2,p2`s, then riffling this with my original vector, then ordering by `x1` and `x2`, and finally summing the elements.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Here's my solution:

I start defining a `positionFinder` function:

```
positionFinder[index_Integer,n_]:=  
    PadLeft[IntegerDigits[index,MixedRadix[{2n+1,2,2n+1,2}]],4,0] - {n,0,n,0};
```

Then I define `indexes` as `Length[vector[n]]`, and

```
poleposition[n_]:= Table[positionFinder[i-1,n],{i,1,indexes}];
positions[n_]:=
    Partition[Riffle[Part[poleposition[n],All,1],
                     Part[poleposition[n],All,3]],2];
```

So I have the positions list, i.e. an array `{{-n(* ,0 *),-n(* ,0 *))},{-n (* ,0 *),-n (* ,1 *)},{-n(* ,1 *),-n+1(* ,0 *)}, ... , {-n(* ,1 *),-n(* ,0 *)},{-n(* ,1 *),-n(* ,1 *)},{-n(* ,1 *),-n+1(* ,0 *)} ... ,{n(* ,1 *),n(* ,1 *)}}` (I commented the p1,p2 which make my array disordered). Now, I do

```
probGet[n_]:=Partition[Flatten[Riffle[positions[n],vector[n]]],3];
```

to join the positions and their correspondent vector element and

```
probCompute[n_]:=Sort[Sort[probGet[n],#1[[2]]>#2[[2]]&],#1[[1]]<#2[[1]]&];
```

to order my total array by the positions. Finally,

```
probExtract[n_]:= Part[probCompute[n],1;;-1;;4] + Part[probCompute[n],2;;-1;;4] + 
                  Part[probCompute[n],3;;-1;;4] + Part[probCompute[n],4;;-1;;4];
```

Comment: Post your solution! That way if we come up with different solutions, we can test speed against your solution (and we won't reproduce your solution). Also: how is `n` chosen? Is it related to the length of some list? Or is it a parameter in your problem?

Comment: @march that's correct, letters don't matter, that's why I chose j and k at the end. I'll edit the question with my solution.

Comment: I was going to use your code to test my solution against yours, but `MixedRadix` is new in V10.2, which I don't have, so I have another question. How does "summing `a+b+g+h`" result in `{-1, 1}`? That part is unclear. However: your finding of positions and such is unnecessary, because of you just `Sort` your list of 4-tuples, it will bring it automatically into the form you want. You can then `Partition[ ..., 4]` and sum over those rows. I can show this if you can clear up the part about the final summation.

Comment: Summing a+b+g+h means summing the elements which are indexed by the same position.
In the end, I'll have a vector like `{{-1,-1,a+b+g+h}, ... ,{1,1,j+k+y+z}}`.

So "summing" does not result in `{-1,-1}`, they simply become "associated". I'm sorry if I'm being unclear.

Comment: Ok, I edited again, I hope it's clearer now

Comment: Okay, sorry, one more question. When you do `a+b+g+h`, the result should be a 4-element list, is that correct?

Comment: No, it's a three-element list, which has the two positions and the sum as elements. I do the sum within the list itself, once I've ordered it.

Comment: So you are summing all 16 elements in the four lists `a`, `b`, `g`, and `h`?

Comment: They're numbers, not lists. `a`, `b`, `g` and `h` are the elements of the original vector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30596/discussion-between-march-and-enzo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I cannot reproduce the ordering of your original list, I will make my own:

```
orderingList = RandomSample[
 Flatten[
   Outer[Riffle, Tuples[Range[-n, n], 2], Tuples[{0, 1}, 2], 1, 1]
  , 1];
```

We then get the correct ordering of this list by using `SortBy` with a custom ordering function using `SortBy`:

```
ordering = Last /@ SortBy[MapIndexed[Flatten@{#1, #2} &, orderingList], {#[[1]] &, #[[3]] &, #[[2]] &, #[[4]] &}];
```

Finally, we apply this ordering to the original list, partition, and sum. As an example, let's suppose that the values `{a, b, c, ...}` are

```
vals = Array[v, 36];
```

Then:

```
summedVals = Total /@ Partition[vals[[ordering]], 4];
```

should do the trick. Finally, add back in the coordinates, which we didn't have to keep track of because *Mathematica* sorts things consistently:

```
MapThread[Append[#1, #2] &, {Tuples[Range[-1, 1], 2], summedVals}]
```

Comment: Ok, it works perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

**Proposition**

```
listForComponent[vec_, n_] := Flatten[
   Table[{x1, p1, x2, p2, 
          vec[[4 (2 n + 1) (x1 + n) + 2 (2 n + 1) p1 + 2 (x2 + n) + p2 + 1]]}, 
         {x1, -n, n}, {p1, 0, 1}, {x2, -n, n}, {p2, 0, 1}], 
   {1, 2, 3, 4}];

gatherComponents[vec_, n_] := GatherBy[listForComponent[vec, n],
                                        {#[[1]], #[[3]]} &];

addComponents[{{x1_, _, x2_, _, c1_}, {x1_, _, x2_, _, c2_}, 
               {x1_, _, x2_, _, c3_}, {x1_, _, x2_, _, c4_}}] := 
   {x1, x2, c1 + c2 + c3 + c4};

toNewVector[vec_, n_] := addComponents /@ gatherComponents[vec, n];
```

**Explanation**

I explain the above code by means of the following test vector:

```
testvector = Join[CharacterRange["a", "z"], CharacterRange["A", "J"]];
testvector // Short

(* {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", <<26>>, "F", "G", "H", "I", "J"} *)
```

`listForComponent` generates the indices `{x1, p1, x2, p2}` for each vector component. The assignment follows the structure you detailed in your example and is given in the form `{x1, p1, x2, p2, *Component*}`.

```
listForComponent[testvector, 1] // Short

(* {{-1, 0, -1, 0, "a"}, {-1, 0, -1, 1, "b"}, <<33>>, {1, 1, 1, 1, "J"}} *)
```

`gatherComponents` gathers the vector components with respect to their values `{x1, x2}`.

```
gatherComponents[testvector, 1] // Short

(* {{{-1, 0, -1, 0, "a"}, {-1, 0, -1, 1, "b"}, {-1, 1, -1, 0, "g"}, 
     {-1, 1, -1, 1, "h"}}, <<8>>} *)
```

`addComponents` provides the sum of the vector components having the same `{x1, x2}`, and returns a list of the form `{x1, x2, *SumOfComponents*}`.

At last, `toNewVector`, the main function, uses `addComponents` on the output given by `gatherComponents` to return the result sought-after.

```
toNewVector[testvector, 1]

(* {{-1, -1, "a" + "b" + "g" + "h"}, {-1, 0, "c" + "d" + "i" + "j"}, 
    {-1, 1, "e" + "f" + "k" + "l"}, {0, -1, "m" + "n" + "s" + "t"}, 
    {0, 0, "o" + "p" + "u" + "v"}, {0, 1, "q" + "r" + "w" + "x"}, 
    {1, -1, "E" + "F" + "y" + "z"}, {1, 0, "A" + "B" + "G" + "H"}, 
    {1, 1, "C" + "D" + "I" + "J"}} *)
```

**Comments**

Given a vector and a specification `n`, the code will work only if the length of the vector is greater or equal to `4(2n+1)(2n+1)`. The "equal situation" has been shown above; for the "greater situation" the code will apply on the first `4(2n+1)(2n+1)` components.

**Timings**

Here are some timings on my computer.

For `n = 1` and an initial vector of length `36` ("equal situation")

```
Mean@Table[AbsoluteTiming[toNewVector[testvector, 1]][[1]], 1000]

(* 0.000367063 *)
```

For `n = 2` and an initial vector of length `100` ("equal situation")

```
ltestvector = Array[v, 100];
Mean@Table[AbsoluteTiming[toNewVector[ltestvector, 2]][[1]], 1000]

(* 0.00105849 *)
```